# How to enable config file for Android MPlayer

Tags: android, video-streaming, mplayer

I have downloaded MPlayer from Android market and it works quite well.
But inspection of libmplayer.so (downloaded with the Android app) appears to reference all command-line options, mplayer.conf, log.txt, 
and everything else needed to set options and get log output, but it's unclear how to enable these.

When apps are ported from Linux to Android, is there a standard procedure for enabling config files?

Reference links: 

[MPlayer – changing ‘ao=’ codec order in mplayer.conf does not appear to work for per user config?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25760628/mplayer-changing-ao-codec-order-in-mplayer-conf-does-not-appear-to-work-for)

[How to execute the dex file in android with command?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10199863/how-to-execute-the-dex-file-in-android-with-command)

[How to start an Android application from the command line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6613889/how-to-start-an-android-application-from-the-command-line)

Answer (score 0):

You might find config files in (hidden) .mplayer or mplayer folder in home directory.

**However..**

I suggest buying MX Player. It supports most video formats and streaming, and lets you use custom version of ffmpeg.

> In Recent version of MX Player DTS & DOLBY audio codec supports are removed from the official MX-Player. If your video has dts/dtshd/ac3/eac3/mlp audio tracks it won't play any audio.

ffmpeg version with extra codecs is available [here](http://forum.xda-developers.com/apps/mx-player/mx-player-custom-codec-dts-support-t2156254).

Comment: Thank you for you reply. But I am not able to find .mplayer(hidden) or mplayer folder anywhere in Android. I can see these folders in Linux but not in Android.

Comment: Also thank you for suggesting MXPlayer. I have already tried that but my options are limited to open source players only and MXPlayer is not open source.